# btrfs recover: reliable or last-straw?

Tags: data-recovery, disaster-recovery, btrfs

The chunk tree of a btrfs filesystem corrupted and I could not recreate it after hour-long reconstruction. As a last resort (besides restoring from backup) I could use `btrfs restore -S -x -m -v` to get all the files back.

Does anyone know whether the restore is a best-effort way of accessing the data and corruption might be expected or is it reliable and all files that were saved can be assumed healthy - at least when no warnings or errors were reported? I could restore from backup but this would be very time consuming.

Are you storing file checksums and file permissions on disk as a safety measure for your archive storage in case you need recovery?

Answer (score 1):

As read from the [man page:](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Restore)

`The btrfs restore utility is a non-destructive method for **attempting** to recover data from an unmountable filesystem`

So I would definitely put it in the "last-straw" category. As such, I do not expect for it to made any guarantee on the consistency/integrity of recovered files (even if it seems to work quite well for people using it).